# Proxying inside an Android application

Tags: android, proxy, reverse-engineering, mitmproxy

I'm trying to teach myself reverse engineering of Android apps, and at the moment I'm fully running, albeit with a question that lacks an answer:

Via **MITMProxy** I can change Request body and Response body with intercept and Python scripts, but is this possible to include in the app itself, so I do not have to have **MITMProxy** running on a computer, but instead the app automatically proxies to my backend?
So if the app wants an answer from https://api.example.com/get-posts?id=1, then instead I have somehow patched the app to ask my backend https://api.mybackend.com/get-posts?id=1. I cheat the app into thinking it receives a response from the real URL, but instead it connects to my backend and my backend provides a manipulated response.

Comment: Android does not have app specific proxy settings so only redirecting traffic of one will be difficult. For changing apps you may consider a hooking framework like Frida which can be embedded into the app using it's gadget. Then you could even fake the HTTP response without an actual network request.

Comment: @Robert Thank you. I have already used Frida for SSL pinning so I will definetly look into that. Do you by any chance have a link to an example?